# Configuring Grails Plugins with Nexus Repository

Tags: maven-2, plugins, grails, nexus

I'm searching for a longer time, but without any solution.

My problem:

I configured my Grails project (1.2.4) with Maven and my own Nexus Repo. That seems to be working well. But can I also put the Grails plugins, which I am using, also to the Nexus Repo? 
At the momement the plugin dependencies are resolved over the Grails Plugin repository.

Any ideas?

with regards

Fabian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails 1.3 has got support for dependency managing plugins. Details are here:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/05/18/managing-plugins-with-grails-1-3/

The article discusses some of the problems that existing in previous versions of Grails.

Answer (score 2):

Understand this thread is old, but posting a link in which the author explains the configuration of grails to fetch plugins and dependencies from Nexus:

[Nexus Configuration for Grails plugins and other dependencies](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2012/06/04/seriously-offline-grails-going-totally-sans-internet-with-nexus.html)

This worked great for grails 2.2.2.